# Saber si json devuelto es null

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, json

tengo un json devuelto que tiene un valor null, o un valor String,  lo puedo ver con console.log, pero no consigo que me funcione un if para un valor null, ni para un valor String.

El js es éste:

```
function existeProyectoActivo() {
   $.post("funciones.php", {orden: 'existeProyectoActivo'},
   function (nombre) {
      console.log(nombre);
      if (nombre === null) {
         alert("Existe otro proyecto activo. Si crea este proyecto con el \n\
            campo \"Activo\" seleccionado, se desactivará el otro \n\
            proyecto y se incluirá en él la fecha de ayer como fecha final.");
      }     
   });
}
```

La consulta a BD es ésta:

```
public function existeProyectoActivo($usuario) {
      self::accesoDB();
      try {
         $consulta = "SELECT nombre FROM Proyecto WHERE usuario = :usuario and"
                 . " activo = true";
         $resultado = self::$conexion->prepare($consulta);
         $resultado->bindParam(":usuario", $usuario);
         $resultado->execute();
         $nombre = null;
         if ($resultado->rowCount() > 0) {
            $row = $resultado->fetch();
            $nombre = (string)$row['nombre'];
         }
         return $nombre;
      } catch (PDOExceptio $e) {
         echo "Código de error: " . $e->getCode() . "<br />";
         echo "Mensaje: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
      }
   }
```

El código en php es éste:

```
case "existeProyectoActivo":
         $nombreProyectoActivo = DB::existeProyectoActivo($_SESSION['usuario']->getLogin());
         echo json_encode($nombreProyectoActivo);
         break;
```

Tanto si tengo una respuesta de un String, como si es null, la respuesta que obtengo siempre es la misma. He probado en el if: nombre === null, nombre != null, nombre.length == 0, jQuery.isEmptyObject(nombre) -esto siempre da null- , nombre[0] === null; tambien he probado a asignar el valor de "nombre" a una variable, pero nada me funciona. 
Gracias.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que estas mandando un texto plano, y `$.post` espera un objeto JSON del tipo `{ nombre: "Producto" }` de lo contrario no recibirá nada, ni mostrara nada

Comment: @RimuruTempest el JSON se devuelve desde aquí: `echo json_encode($nombreProyectoActivo);`

Comment: Si haces como indiqué en mi respuesta la comparación tiene que ser así: **`if (nombre.error) {`** para que determine si el json tiene una clave `error` o no. Si no funciona quizá tengas que aplicar `JSON.parse` antes de hacer el `if` como indiqué en uno de mis comentarios en mi respuesta. Si no funciona, por favor muestra lo que imprime la consola, a ver si no hay otro problema de codificación por ejemplo o si está devolviendo un objeto mal formado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí lo más seguro sería recoger en la respuesta dos posibilidades no cubiertas. Para hacerlo, puedes poner un `else` para recoger la posibilidad de cero filas encontradas, generando ahí un array con una clave `error` y un mensaje que puedes usar para informar al cliente de lo que ocurrió en el servidor. La posibilidad de error en la consulta se podría retornar también igualmente al final del bloque `try ... catch`.

En tu código no puedes emitir `echo` en ningún momento, porque si sale cualquier cosa por pantalla el json podría ser incorrecto en esos casos, y tu retorno a la función que llama no sería coherente.

También, te falta una `n` al final aquí: `PDOExceptio`. Y, conviene que especifiques el estilo `fetch` de forma explícita, de lo contrario podría estar trayéndote los datos en forma de array asociativo y numérico.

Otra cosa (que se ha verificado posteriormente en comentarios) es que la respuesta en el cliente no está siendo reconocida como json, sino como texto. Convendría dar más coherencia al código, indicando en el cliente que se espera un tipo de datos json, y poniendo en el servidor un `header` adecuado que indique que lo que se emite es un json (si te interesa hacerlo así puedo poner un ejemplo). De ese modo, no haría falta parsear los datos, lo cual implica posibles riesgos de producir un json inválido, por ejemplo cuando vienen datos con caracteres especiales debido a que la codificación en el servidor no es la más adecuada.

Puedes intentar así:

```
public function existeProyectoActivo($usuario) {
      self::accesoDB();
      try {
         $consulta = "SELECT nombre FROM Proyecto WHERE usuario = :usuario and"
                 . " activo = true";
         $resultado = self::$conexion->prepare($consulta);
         $resultado->bindParam(":usuario", $usuario);
         $resultado->execute();
         if ($resultado->rowCount() > 0) {
            $row = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $nombre = (string)$row['nombre'];
         } else {
            $nombre=["error"=>"No es encontraron filas"];
         }
         return $nombre;
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
          return ["error"=>"Hubo un error en la consulta"];
      }
      $nombre=["error"=>"La consulta falló"];
      return $nombre;
   }
```

Y en la verificación haces esta evaluación `if (nombre.error) {`, quedando así el código:

```
function existeProyectoActivo() {
   $.post("funciones.php", {orden: 'existeProyectoActivo'},
   function (nombre) {
      /*Esto sólo es necesario cuando no se ha indicado de otro modo el datatype*/
      json=JSON.parse(nombre);
      console.log(json);
      /*Aquí comprobamos si el dato parseado tiene o no una clave error*/
      if (json.error) {
         alert("Existe otro proyecto activo. Si crea este proyecto con el \n\
            campo \"Activo\" seleccionado, se desactivará el otro \n\
            proyecto y se incluirá en él la fecha de ayer como fecha final.");
      }     
   });
}
```

Así estandarizas, devolviendo siempre un json válido que contenga información útil para el cliente.

---

## Ejemplo poniendo el dataType

### En el cliente

Para que esto funcione necesitas tener una librería de jQuery actualizada. Considera agregar a tu proyecto [la librería más reciente](https://code.jquery.com).

```
function existeProyectoActivo() {
    $.post( "funciones.php", {orden: 'existeProyectoActivo'}, 
        function( nombre ) {
            if (json.error) {
                alert("Existe otro proyecto activo. Si crea este proyecto con el \n\
                       campo \"Activo\" seleccionado, se desactivará el otro \n\
                       proyecto y se incluirá en él la fecha de ayer como fecha final.");
            }     

        }, "json");     
}
```

Haciendo eso ya no necesitas aplicar `JSON.parse` como anteriormente.

### En el servidor

Para completar el contexto, conviene que pongas un `header` también en PHP antes de devolver los datos. OJO con esto, cuando usas `header` en PHP debes cuidar que no salga por pantalla nada antes de eso.

```
case "existeProyectoActivo":
         $nombreProyectoActivo = DB::existeProyectoActivo($_SESSION['usuario']->getLogin());
         header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
         echo json_encode($nombreProyectoActivo);
         break;
```

Dado que veo que estás en un contexto de `switch ... case` quizá convendría organizar mejor el código para no estar repitiendo `N` veces el header o los `echo`. Eso se haría guardando el resultado en una variable e imprimiéndola al final del bloque `switch`, eso no será difícil de adaptar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. He intentado todas las modificaciones, al pie de la letra, y me sigue pasando lo mismo: En la consola veo el mensaje de error o el nombre, según el usuario que escoja, pero el código sigue pasando por el mismo camino en el if, como si todo fuera igual. Debo tener algo mal en alguna otra parte, que no alcanzo a ver.

Comment: @RaúlSoriaOrtiz es muy probable que la petición te esté dando los datos como html, por lo pronto prueba a hacer algo así: **`function (nombre) { json=JSON.parse(nombre);
      console.log(json);
      if (json.error) { //resto el código `** Dime si funciona así, y si no muestra lo que aparece en la consola.

Comment: @RaúlSoriaOrtiz mucho ojo a esto, yo propongo que si implementas mi solución hagas la evaluación asi: **`if (nombre.error) { `** donde `nombre` sería la respuesta que obtuviste del servidor. Si es un JSON válido, el `if` escrito así **`if(nombre.error)`** determinará si el json tiene una clave `error` o no. Lo digo porque en la edición de la pregunta veo que no usas esa forma de evaluar, si no lo haces así no funcionará. Si no funciona es quizá porque no lo está mandando como json y tendrás que aplicar `JSON.parse` como indiqué en mi anterior comentario.

Comment: ¡Genial! Ya funciona. El problema estaba estaba en que yo había probado JSON.parse(nombre) después del if, y como funciona es ANTES del if. Creo que estaría bien que modificaras el código que pusiste como solución, para incluir esto del JSON.parse(nombre) antes del if, pues así le servirá a más gente.  Tenía varios métodos atascados con ésto, ya estaba desesperado. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: @RaúlSoriaOrtiz voy a modificar la respuesta en ese sentido. Aunque aún esto del JSON.parse es una solución intermedia, que sugerí en comentarios por ser más simple. Quizá sería más conveniente indicar a la petición un dataType: json y en el servidor poner un `header` que indique igualmente un `application/json`, de ese modo das más coherencia al código y no te ves obligado a parsear la respuesta, lo cual implica siempre un riesgo de error.

Comment: @ ACedano Sería estupendo si pones un ejemplo de header como has ofrecido.

Comment: @RaúlSoriaOrtiz te he puesto un ejemplo al final.

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias cosas que puedes hacer para mejorar el código si tienes una versión reciente de PHP. Mira:

```php
public function existeProyectoActivo($usuario) {
      self::accesoDB();
      try {
         $consulta = "SELECT nombre FROM Proyecto WHERE usuario = :usuario and"
                 . " activo = true LIMIT 1";
         $resultado = self::$conexion->prepare($consulta);
         $resultado->bindParam(":usuario", $usuario);
         $resultado->execute();

         if ($resultado->rowCount() > 0) {
            $row = $resultado->fetch();
            $nombre = (string) $row['nombre'];
         }
         return $nombre ?? '';
      } catch (PDOExceptio $e) {
         echo "Código de error: " . $e->getCode() . "<br />";
         echo "Mensaje: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
      }
   }
```

En primer lugar, fíjate que es importante limitar el número de resultados devueltos por MySQL poniendo `LIMIT 1` en la consulta SQL. Así, te aseguras que tú código siempre vaya a funcionar aunque tu base de datos se corrompa.

En segundo lugar, ¿ por qué devolver `null` ?. Hay que ser coherentes en la medida de lo posible y si tu función devuelve una cadena cuando cuando el valor es correcto, también debería de devolver una cadena en caso incorrecto. Fíjate hemos eliminado la asignación a `null` y la devolución ahora es:

```
return $nombre ?? '';
```

Esto significa que si nombre no existiera que se use cadena vacía( '' ).

Luego en el javascript:

```
function existeProyectoActivo() {
   $.post("funciones.php", {orden: 'existeProyectoActivo'},
   function (nombre) {
      console.log(nombre);
      if ('' === nombre) {
         alert("Existe otro proyecto activo. Si crea este proyecto con el \n\
            campo \"Activo\" seleccionado, se desactivará el otro \n\
            proyecto y se incluirá en él la fecha de ayer como fecha final.");
      }     
   });
}
```

Fíjate, ahora se comprueba contra cadena vacía y no contra null. Ahora debería de funcionar corréctamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. He intentado todas las modificaciones, al pie de la letra, y me sigue pasando lo mismo: En la consola veo las comillas sin contenido o las comillas con contenido, según el usuario que escoja, pero el código sigue pasando por el mismo camino en el if, como si todo fuera igual. Debo tener algo mal en alguna otra parte, que no alcanzo a ver.

Comment: y si quitas el if, pero deja el alert después del console.log. ¿ te salta el alert ?. Otra opción es probar a reemplazar el alert por un console.log.  Quizás el if te está funcionando pero lo que no te funciona es lo que hay dentro del if( o sea, el alert ).